# Azure Multi-tenant Web Api - can only have one Audience

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory

I have a OWIN Web Api that requires `ida:Audience` param to validate the JWT

```
public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = Config.GetSetting("ida:Audience"),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
            };
```

This means that I can only have a single Client App that can connect to my Web Api.  There seems to be no way to add additional Audiences.
Hence, if I wan to connect other client apps to my web api, i have to change the Audience..
This doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your API receives an Access Token, the Audience Claim `aud` in that token should be for your API. This means that no matter which client calls your Web API, the audience claim should be the same.

If you want to uniquely identify the client application calling your web api, you should look at the `appid` claim.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: But what If I want to specify a list of clients that can connect to my API?

Comment: Can you reference the notion that "aud in that token should be for your API"?

Comment: There different ways you can specify only a select number of services to be able to call your Web API. The most straight forward way imo would be for your API to check the `appid` claim in the token, and compare it to a white-list of services which are allowed to call your API. Let me give you a specific example for `aud` claim. When you get a token to the Microsoft Graph, no matter what client you call from, the `aud` claim is `aud: https://graph.microsoft.com/`. The Microsoft Graph checks this property to ensure that the token was meant for this resource, and denies any token otherwise.

Comment: Here is [the specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.3) that requires this. `The "aud" (audience) claim identifies the recipients that the JWT is intended for.  Each principal intended to process the JWT MUST identify itself with a value in the audience claim.  If the principal processing the claim does not identify itself with a value in the "aud" claim when this claim is present, then the JWT MUST be rejected.`